# Python - compare two lists' values AND lengths

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, `list1` and `list2`. For each value in `list1`, I need to find elements in `list2` which satisy the two following conditions:

- The `list1` element must be a substring of any `list2` element (for example 'ABC' in `list1` is a substring of 'ABCDE' in `list2`)
- The length of the `list1` element must be shorter than the length of the `list2` element ('ABC' is shorter than 'ABCDE').

I then want to pass any qualifying element in `list2` to a separate `list3`. I'm having a lot of trouble getting around the syntax to implement this.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
for elem in list1:
    if elem in list2 and len(elem) < len(range(list2)):
        list3.append(list2)
```

I realise the '`len(range(list2))`' is wrong but it's as close as I can get to what I think is right. I'm not clear on how to 'extract' the particular elements which qualify and add them to my list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: if it is required that list2 element has to be a substring, why do you even compare length afterwards? it needs to be shorter to be a substring

Comment: please show input & expected output. an example is better than a thousand words... My crystal ball tells me that you need `all(len(elem) < len(x) for x in list2)` though. or `any`... oh well... unclear

Comment: @Cut7er a substring is not necessary shorter than the parent string: it may be equal. i.e. `'ABC'` is a substring of `'ABC'`, but it is not a valid answer for the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
list3 = [i for i in list1 if any(i in j and len(i) < len(j) for j in list2)]
```

For example, if:

```
list1 = ['ABC', 'BCD', 'ABCDE', 'DEF']
list2 = ['ABCDE', 'XYZ']
```

then with the above code, `list3` would become:

```
['ABC', 'BCD']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["ABC", "CD", "XX", "AA", "GG"]    
list2 = ["BABCD", "CC", "XY", "AAA", "GG"]
list3 = []
for item in list1:
    for other_item in list2:
        if item in other_item and len(item) < len(other_item):
            list3.append(item)
```

Output:

```
>>> list3
['ABC', 'CD', 'AA']
```